# Invalid number of arguments in equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

## y = |sin(x)| + 5*exp(-x^100)*cos(x)  from -3 to 3

```
x = np.linspace(-3,3)
y = np.mod(np.sin(x)) + 5*np.exp(-x**100)*np.cos(x)  #from -3 to 3

ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

i want to plot this equation but can't compile it

Comment: Note that `np.exp(-x**100)` will be subject to over and underflow. The result might not be nearly as accurate as you want or need it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `np.mod` is not the absolute value function that you are expecting it to be, but is instead related to [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and you need to provide it two values to correctly calculate the result. For example `np.mod(5, 3) == 2` as 5 is congruent to 2 modulo 3.

The function call you are wanting is `np.absolute`, which whill give you the absolute value of the provided argument.

Answer (score 5):

In  [np.mod](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) you need to specify the second argument (the divisor). For example,

```
np.mod(np.sin(x),2)
```

In addition, as @Jake Conkerton-Darby mentioned in his anwers, if you want to calculate absolute value you should use [np.absolute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) and not np.mod.